# How to create a sidebar menu in Win32 C++

Tags: c++, user-interface, win32gui

I'm new to WIN32 and I can do the top (regular) menu bar. I want to create a sidebar menu just like the image below, is it even possible to do so in WIN32 C++? if so, any tutorials or hints would be appreciated.

[image: SideBar Menu]

Comment: Why don't you try googling: "win32 c++ sidebar" ?

Comment: @ZivS I tried with no success :(

Comment: Well, please first, this is a guide for asking questions on this website: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Your question is too broad. You did not mention which GUI framework you are using, and have not shown any attempts that you have tried. When I google  "win32 c++ sidebar" the first link (after the link to this question) is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21780505/creating-guis-in-win32-c , start there, or google "win32 c++ gui tutorial" and start there. Once you have a specific problem that you need assistance, ask a specific question

Comment: Don't know why someone -1 this question. OP question is about sidebar in Common Control Library inside [Windows API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API#Overview). Pleas do not -1 questions that you do not understand.

Comment: @Logman Finally someone got the point